# MS Access 2016 Error: "Multi-level group by not allowed"

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

i'm stuck at another point in my little Access 2016 Database. My code looks like the following and i know it probably isn't the cleanest solution but i'm kinda new to this and i tried to educate myself and get some help here already.

I'm trying to play around with the reports now a little bit and i am using this test query which returns all entries of two tables joined together.

As far as i could find out I have this one subquery included that returns the prvious day inventory for each record and that is most likely the cause of my error. I found a possible solution with adding SELECT * FROM at the beginning of my code but i get a Syntax error when i do that and i'm not sure how to solve this problem.

here's my code

`SELECT Stations.StationName, Product.ProductName, GasInventoryTransactions.TransactionDate, (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.ActualInventory                    FROM GasInventory AS Dupe                         WHERE Dupe.StationID = Stations.StationID      AND Dupe.ProductID = Product.ProductID       AND Dupe.InventoryDate < GasInventory.InventoryDate       ORDER BY Dupe.InventoryDate DESC) AS PreviousDayInventory, GasInventory.ActualInventory, GasInventoryTransactions.GasSales, GasInventoryTransactions.GasDelivery, [PreviousDayInventory]+[GasDelivery]-[GasSales] AS BookBalance, GasInventory.ActualInventory, [ActualInventory]-[BookBalance] AS OverShort
FROM (Stations INNER JOIN (Product INNER JOIN GasInventory ON Product.[ProductID] = GasInventory.[ProductID]) ON Stations.[StationID] = GasInventory.[StationID]) INNER JOIN GasInventoryTransactions ON GasInventory.[InventoryDate] = GasInventoryTransactions.[TransactionDate];`

thanks for your help!

Comment: I would suggest that you start by cleaning up and formatting your code.

Comment: The issue possibly the calcs that reference the constructed fields PreviousDayInventory and BookBalance. Remove the calcs and see if it runs. If it does, then build another query that references this one to do the calcs.

Comment: Thank you @SunKnight0 for the helpful comment, i know i'm a beginner myself, nevertheless i try to somehow make the thing work.I'm very sorry that i don't understand SQL as perfect as you do yet

Comment: @June7 i deleted the subquery in the query and now the report is working. So you were right, thank you for the suggestion.
What exactly do you mean by build another query? A seperate query? How do i link those seperate ones to an existing one then?

Comment: I did not suggest removing the subquery, but removing the calculated fields. How can the report provide the PreviousDayInventory without the subquery? Queries can be used in queries, just like tables. So you could build another query that pulls from the working query and do calcs there.